# laravel password reset using phone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i am using Laravel 5.4.17 i changed login field from `email` to `phone`.

but in password reset, when user changed his password, (email - new password - password confirm) the browser will ask for save new password and the email will save as password in input

i don't want to change reset password form email to another. but my problem is after send email, when user is changing his password (first field is email and i want browser dont save it as username)

Comment: have tried doing yourself..? if yes, then please post code..

Comment: @Zaheer Attar .  no im using laravel default Auth system and everything is default now and i just changed logging in from email to phone

Answer (score 0):

Use the `username()` method on your `User` model to return the identifier column name...

```
public function username()
{
    return 'phone';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: no. its not working . the problem is from browser . when user insert his email and his new passwords, the email will save in browser autocomplete as username

Answer (score -1):

In 5.4 you need to override the following function

```
public function username()
```

Look in: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

The default is to return email:

```
public function username()

{
        return 'email';
}
```

After adding the fields in your db, you can override as follows in your controller

```
public function username()
{
        return 'phone';
}
```

add 1 more column in user table name phone 
hope its work fine

Comment: i think you dont understand my mean.  i did it before ... i changed the email to phone . and i have phone in db and users can login as phone. my problem is just and just in password reset . when password will change , the browser will ask for save new password and the email will save in username inputs (in browser) just browser

Comment: i have not good knowledge in cookie but your solution is on laravel cookie who can handle your browser cookie better